# reset and restart animation on button click

Tags: javascript, animation, event-handling, css-animations, event-listener

i have a button element that plays a random audio file from an array each time it is clicked. i would also like to have it play an animation when it is clicked, and be reset and replay every time after it is click.  the code below is what I have so far, this works however the animation only plays one time and then the button element is static after that. any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

```
#button {
animation: color 2s linear;
animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes color {
from {background-color: red;}
to {background-color: blue;}
}
```

```
<button id="button">Click To Play</button>
```

```
const sounds = [
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3",
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3",
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3",
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3"
];

const audio = new Audio();

function playSound(){
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);
  audio.src = sounds[rand];
  audio.play();
}

button.addeventlistener('click',function1);

function function1(){
button.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'running'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what's happening is you are playing the animation, it's getting to the end, but then it doesn't get reset.

You could use animation-name in your css, and then in js, clear the animation name, and then reset it to play your animation again.

Another approach would be to put the animation-name onto a separate class, and then add/remove that class on your element as needed.